# RX/TX communication LEDs

Tags: led, communication

I need to indicate the RX/TX functioning using LEDs. Due to lack of space I was thinking about using bicolour LEDs. The question is: how fast will the colours be changing? Will it be visible? Or are they going to change too fast to be recognizable?

I appreciate it if anyone can suggest anything.

Comment: Depends how fast the link you're monitoring is running.

Comment: It depends to what you connect them to and how fast the LEDs are being blinked. Is it an Ethernet chip, USB serial chip, or other chip with indicator outputs, or are you directly connecting the LEDs to say UART data run at 3 Mbps?

Comment: I have RX/TX in different chips, Rs232/485 and SCI to USB.

Comment: That didn’t answer Justme’s question. How fast do you blink them?

Answer (score 4):

If you connect the LEDs directly to the RX/TX lines, you'll never recognise a substantial blink because human eye is not that fast. Therefore, the faster the communication (or the higher the bitrate), the less recognisable a blink. What you'll possibly see is a **flicker** instead.

A blink has clear on, off and transitions:

[image]

But flicker gives a totally different feeling:

[image]

It's obvious that the LED is turning on and off but your eye cannot catch these transitions. 1s and 0s in the message will form a PWM having dynamically changing duty cycle (duty cycle is determined by 1 or 0 density). This will bring varying brightness like shown in the gif above. And if there's a time frame when there's no transmission it'll be clearly seen (see the green LED is off for a few milliseconds).

Now in light of the information given above, I can say that you won't see your bi-colour LED blinking. Instead, what you'll see is a flickering LED with constantly changing colour (and maybe brightness). For a red-green LED, depending on the message content, you'll see the LED changing colours dynamically between reddish orange, orange, yellow and yellowish green.

Answer (score 2):

The colors will change almost instantaneously (less than a microsecond). Whether that is perceptible depends on the duration of the changed color. If it's long enough that it represents a significant fraction of 100ms it should be perceptible as a fluctuation in color.

A blink from off to on would be perceptible with a shorter pulse again, particularly with a bright LED in subdued light.

If you want to ensure that the LED changes are perceptible even with very short transmissions at very high baud rates you can trigger a [one-shot](https://ttps://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g123.pdf) with an edge and stretch the pulse to something like 250ms.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand your question to be asking is:

- When I switch a bi-colour LEDs from one colour to the other, how quickly can the LED change from one colour to the other.

So, does switching it too fast etc. make it show the wrong colours.

If that's your question then...

No. The fastest LED switching that a human to observe and detect is still much slower than the fastest the LED can cleanly switch colours at.

Answer (score 1):

I often use these duo LEDs in such a context, e.g. red for RX and green for TX. If I see red only, there is no local transmission, green only means no RX and all sort of yellow, orange, amber flicker is a proper communication. That is useful for a quick diagnostic, the LEDs are much faster than the human eye anyway.

If you use a LED with two legs only, in full duplex mode the LED is not as bright, because a large part of the time both signals are active and the LED is off. A three legs LED has a small advantage here.

A minor disadvantage is, that it is impossible to log the data with a photo diode in full duplex transmissions.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. Due to lack of space area, I want to use a bi-colour LED. If both RX/TX are functionning, This Bi-colour LED should indicates it by another colour. right? For example if the LED is red and green while we have both signals of RX/TX it should be yellow. (The colours are only as an example).

Answer (score 1):

Because I wasn't satisfied using simple LED's as indicators for RX/TX traffic, I found another way with a minimum of parts. Just take an ATTiny (I used an ATTiny84) with internal clock of 8MHz to observe the RX/TX-Lines of 2 USARTS and other 4 Pins to drive 4 LED's. And a little piece of assembler-code. I tested this up to 115200 Baud and it worked fine all the time.